# Can you embed https certificate in bokeh application? Python

Tags: python, https, bokeh

We have configured a bokeh application in python and would like to serve it with https on a windows system. Is there a way to embed the certificate information for https into the bokeh application itself, so it serves https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version `0.13.0`, Bokeh does not currently have any built in capability to serve HTTPS. In order to serve HTTPS you would need to run the Bokeh server behind a proxy that terminates the SSL connection. There are specific instructions for doing this with Nginx in the docs: [Reverse Proxying with Nginx and SSL](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#reverse-proxying-with-nginx-and-ssl)

Comment: It should, reverse proxying like that is general thing that is independent of Bokeh or anything else. It only requires that the proxy can terminate any SSL connections and route them appropriately to the internal server.